# uninitialized constant Capybara (NameError) in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

> c:/mowes/www/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `block
>   in ': uninitialized constant Capybara (NameError)

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

I have `gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'` in my Gemfile so I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could work. Try adding these lines in `spec_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
 config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
 config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
 config.order = "random" 
 config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Comment: I see my mistake. Instead of adding the include line to the code, I removed all the code to replace it.

Answer (score 20):

You have to add  `config.include Capybara::DSL` to `rails_helper.rb`, and not into `spec_helper.rb`. It worked for me perfectly!

Comment: This worked for me too. Was following http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#cha-static_pages but using the latest versions of rails and capabara. Something must have changed.

Answer (score 5):

Did you already run bundle install?  Have you added

```
require 'capybara/rails'
```

in rails_helper.rb

If you are using Capybara you might want to follow the instructions [here](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2011/05/03/uninitialized-constant-capybara-nameerror-rails-3-0-7/).

Answer (score 2):

If you see this error in your specs, despite importing Capybara in `spec_helper.rb`, adding `.rspec` with the line `--require spec_helper` to the root ought to fix the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm added  `config.include Capybara::DSL to rails_helper.rb`, and not into `spec_helper.rb`. and it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I also countered to this question. I was learning MOOC, and test file was copyed from another place. Because .repec was hide file, so when I copied, this file was not copied. 
I use Command + shift +. to show the file and copy it to project root directory, and the issue was solved.